# How to extract XML tag contents using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My ASP.NET MVC4 controller returns an XML string, when we pass it a **SERIAL**. Now when I send a request using C#, it works fine, XML string comes back , and looks like

```
<CalculatedCode> 12312312 </CalculatedCode>
```

I need to also do it via jquery like below. Query is working but it is returning an `XMLDocumentObject` , instead of an `xml string`. I looked at Jquery documentation to try to parse it, but I'm a jquery noob and I'm sure I'm making an error in the code.

```
              $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
                 type: 'GET',
                 dataType: 'xml',
                 data: { SERIAL: serial}, //SERIAL comes from a textbox
                 success: function (responseData) {

             //Code below is messed up, it simply needs to find the CalculatedCode tag 
             //and  extract the value within this tag
                     xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response);
                     $xml = $(xmlDoc);                         
                     $thecode = $xml.find("CalculatedCode");  
             // ToDo: Bug stackoverflow members with this noob question          

                 }
             });
```

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already parsed when you set the dataType to XML, so no need for `$.parseXML`, but if the element is a root element, `find()` doesn't work, as it only finds children, you'll need `filter()`

```
$xml     = $(responseData);                         
$thecode = $xml.filter("CalculatedCode").text();
```

an trick that gets the element either way is to append the xml to another element :

```
$xml     = $('<div />').append(responseData);                         
$thecode = $xml.find("CalculatedCode").text();
```